# Somar Valores no AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, mobile

Tenho 5 `inputs` onde entro com alguns valores, porém quando tento fazer a soma o resultado total não é exibido no ultimo `input`.
**HTML:**

```
 <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="cinza input-label">Valor 1</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="var1"> </input></label>
    <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="cinza input-label">Valor 2</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="var2"> </input></label>
    <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="cinza input-label">Valor 3</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="var3"> </input></label>
    <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="cinza input-label">Valor 4</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="var4"> </input></label>
    <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="cinza input-label">Valor 5</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="var5"> </input></label>
    <div ng-controller="Total">
    <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="cinza input-label">Total</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="total"> </input></label></input> 
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('Total', function ($state, $scope) {

$scope.var1 = 0;
$scope.var2 = 0;
$scope.var3 = 0;
$scope.var4 = 0;
$scope.var5 = 0;

var total = $scope.var1 + $scope.var2 + $scope.var3 + $scope.var4 + $scope.var5;

$scope.total = total;

})
```

Como faço pra exibir valor total em um input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não está funcionando pois você não chama nenhuma ação (função) que faz a soma.

Tente o seguinte:

No seu ultimo `input` coloque um [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) ou [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

```
<input type="number" ng-click="somarValores()" ng-blur="somarValores()" ng-model="var5"> </input></label>
```

E no seu Controller:

```
$scope.somarValores = function(){
    $scope.total = $scope.var1 + $scope.var2 + $scope.var3 + $scope.var4 + $scope.var5;
}
```

Exemplo funcionando:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdJmwq

**OBS**: Um trecho do seu html pode apresentar problemas também, não sei como está a estrutura inteira porém reparei que você chama o `Controller` apenas no final do html. Dessa maneira todas as variáveis declaradas no `Controller` só são "enxergadas" no final.

Comment: Cara, já estou conseguido somar, mas ele só ta preenchendo o campo total depois q eu coloco o valor em todos os campos... Da uma olhada aqui: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYxJEG   eu quero exatamente assim, só quero q ele some cada vez q preencho um campo, sem precisar preencher todos.

Comment: No seu Controller você tem que inicializar a variável com 0 e não " ": http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdJmwq

Comment: Não posso exibir os números 0 nas input.

Comment: Então você vai ter que mudar um pouco sua lógica. Vai tentando, vou almoçar já volto pra te ajudar

Comment: Tentei algumas coisas mas nenhuma deu certo... aquele link foi o mais perto q eu cheguei haha

Comment: Cara ai eu já n sei se funciona, pois pelo que eu analisei você precisa inicializar a variável como 0. Você quer atualizar em "tempo real" ou seja, ao entrar com um numero ele começa a soma, mas se você não inicializar a variável não vai funcionar

Comment: Aqui está algo mais próximo do que você precisa: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdJmwq

Comment: Mas só funciona se você definir todos os numeros

Comment: Baah cara, valeu pela ajuda, vou continuar tentando aqui... Se tiver alguma ideia pode avisa, se eu conseguir também te aviso.

Comment: Tudo bem, boa sorte :D

Comment: Consegui cara: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYxJEG

Answer (score 4):

A afirmação da outra resposta é verdadeira e funciona, porém como alternativa, caso queira colocar o valor na propriedade total, pode ser utilizada uma função auto-executável, como:

```
$scope.total = (function(){
   $scope.var1 + $scope.var2 + $scope.var3 + $scope.var4 + $scope.var5;
})();
```

Comment: Eu preciso exibir esse Total no ultimo input.

Answer (score 0):

Se alguém ainda estiver com duvida, está Resolvido: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYxJEG.